# Are there insulated covers available for attic fans?

Tags: hvac, insulation, attic

I have an attic fan that leaks a lot of attic air down to the living area. Are there insulated covers that can be placed on the underside, living area side of the fan that can insulate from the attic? But can easily be removed if the attic fan is needed? Maybe something that is insulated and magnetic or has velcro?

I've checked with Home Depot and local hardware store with no luck.

Comment: Are you saying that the attic fan is in a living area?  Attics are *meant* to be free-flow air spaces.  If you're getting air leakage from the attic to the living space then the seal between the attic and the living space is the problem.

Comment: The attic fan is in the hallway that meets the living area and kitchen. The vent for the attic fan in the living area is not very well sealed as it is old. It is designed to the lift the shutters up when the fan is on, and they rest closed when the fan is off. I'm looking to cover this up when the attic fan is not in use. 
The attic fan is designed to exhaust hot air in the house into the attic area when the A/C or Heater is not running.

Comment: Ahhh - what you're describing is a "Whole House Fan"

Comment: There is one product matching "whole house fan cover" at home depot: https://www.homedepot.com/p/Battic-Door-Energy-Conservation-Products-3-ft-x-4-ft-Whole-House-Fan-Seal-Radiant-Barrier-with-Hook-and-Loop-Attachment-SMSS/206347508

Comment: Awesome! I've always heard them called "attic fans". No wonder I wasn't finding results. Good to know, thanks for the link and clarification.

Answer (score 2):

Answer: Yes, there are covers available for 'whole house fans' but there is not a huge selection out there.

You might consider making something yourself.

Comment: I've thought about making one as well. I've watched a few YouTube videos if I don't find an easier solution. Thanks